# Why does my Activity in Android Studio have different text color in the code compared to others?

Tags: android-studio

[image]

[image]

In the first photo, the variable names are supposed to be purple. The Override and onCreate are supposed to be yellow, like the rest of my activities. Why is it different?

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild your project and if this still doesn't work then go to
Files -> invalidate cache and restart-> cache and Restart.
This will help u, if still it doesn't work ping me.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. I figured it out, a while ago I turned off the Highlighting Level to None in Customize Highlighting Level options. You adjust it by right-clicking on the scrollbar in your code Editor and clicking on Customize Highlighting Level. I'm not familiar with Android Studio, so I totally forgot about it. I put it back to 'Inspections' level, and it's all back to normal.

Comment: Okay, buddy.. you can let VoteUp my answer or accept it as answer, it will help to grow more